# MVC input button onclick does not work after changing it in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a dropdownlist and button in a page as below:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MovieType")

<input id="btnBk" type="button" value="Back" onclick="location.href = '/Test/Index/'"  />
```

The dropdownlist is populated in the controller:

```
public ActionResult DDL()
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0" });

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", Selected = true });

    items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });

    ViewBag.MovieType = items;

    return View();
}
```

When a dropdownlist item is selected, I try to change the button onclick from the original /Test/Index/ to /Test/Index1 :

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $('#MovieType').change(function () {
        var href = $('#btnBk').attr("onclick");
        alert(href);
        $('#btnBk').attr('onclick', "location.href='/Test/Index1/'");
        href = $('#btnBk').attr("onclick");
        alert(href);
    })
});
```

Alert messages indicate that the onclick value is updated. But when click on the Back button after changing, it has no response instead of redirecting to /Test/Index1.

Is something missing?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the onclick attribute from your element and make it like this.
Make full use of jQuery for your operations.

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
      $('#btnBk').click(function(){
             location.href='/Test/Index/';
        });

    $('#MovieType').change(function () {
        $('#btnBk').unbind('click').click(function(){
             location.href='/Test/Index1/';
        });
    })
});
```